# Decimal to Grey code & Decimal to Binary in PHP

Tags: php, binary, decimal

I want to convert Decimal Number to Binary Number & Decimal number to Grey code in PHP.

Is it possible?

If possible, then how?

Answer (score 0):

use [`decbin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) to convert from decimal to binary,

```
<?php
    echo decbin("3") . "<br>";
    echo decbin("1") . "<br>";
    echo decbin("1587") . "<br>";
    echo decbin("7");
?>
```